# Where I can find graphics to be used in my research papers?

Tags: publications

I found some websites for free graphics like icons. But, they require attribution. to the website. Is there any website that provide free graphics for research purpose without the need of attribution?

Comment: It's possible you can use the icons anyway. As a start I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with the local fair use laws (e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54029/is-it-legal-in-the-us-for-a-student-to-download-a-copy-of-a-textbook-to-study)

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103348/finding-high-quality-copyright-free-icons-for-computer-diagrams-in-ieee-or-acm-s?r=SearchResults

Comment: If you use Latex for typesetting you have the 'fontawesome' package for icons. https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome

Comment: Why is attribution a problem? If they help you then they probably deserve it. If you want to give the impression that they are your own work, it is a form of plagiarism.

Comment: Researchers should make their own graphics or pay for custom graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Pixabay.com and select Vector Graphics and use the search bar.

Rawpic.com and search for your icons, make sure you then click 'free' and 'graphics' you will recieve 7 free downloads a day. If you need more just like their pinterest page and get 10 more.

They both do not require attribution.

Answer (score 2):

phylopic.org has some great animal and plant silhouettes which can be used in your graphics under a Public Domain or Creative Commons license. For instance, silhouettes from phylopic are used in figures in these papers (sorry they might be paywalled):

- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921818116301540#f0005
- https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/evan.21498

Neither of these studies acknowledged or attributed any image to phylopic.org, but some images may need to be acknowledged depending on the license - which can be seen on each image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86608)

Comment: Sorry @AloneProgrammer, I've expanded my answer to give more detail if that's better?

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin provides some suggestions for graphics that do not require attribution, but I gotta ask - why not just attribute the ones you already have appropriately?

In all sites that my students use it is completely acceptable to add a single sentence to the acknowledgements ("Icons in figures 3, 4 and 7 have been produced by user XYZ on ABC"). As long as you clarify copyright questions, this seems substantially easier (and gives you a lot more options) than limiting yourself to visual elements that don't require any sort of attribution.